# Spring WS unmarshaller creates empty request object

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I created spring WS service, have my wsdl and test it with SOAP UI, it works correctly. However, when i get real requests from 3d-party ws client, i get en empty request object created by marshaller. I compared soap envelopes created by SOAP UI and the one i get from real client:

working (created by SOAP UI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope ... xmlns:gen="http://example.com">
    <gen:myExample> ... </gen:myExample>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and not working (geting from real client that i can't change):

```
<soapenv:Envelope ...>
    <myExample xmlns="http://example.com"> ... </myExample>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do i configure my marshaller to force it understand soap messages without namespace prefix?

Comment: From an xml perspective they are basically the same. What is your spring-ws endpoint look like.